# React.js, Displaying Two Svg Images Next To Each Other With Space In Between

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

```
import React from "react";
import python from "../svg/python.svg";
import java from "../svg/java.svg";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={python} alt="python" height="50" />
      <img src={java} alt="java" height="70" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I'm trying to display these two svg icons next to each other, but when they render, they are so close to each other. How would I properly put some space in between them such that they do not border so closely?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try adding some CSS to your component?

Comment: @DennisVash I've tried the borderRadius attribute for img, but nothing seemed to change. I also tried to do leftMargin, rightMargin, but I don't see any difference. Also, I didn't create an svg component either, I'm trying to do this without making an svg component.

Comment: You should show us what you tried, better add a codesandbox example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it. Add a css file to your src folder. Give it a name. Here I name it App.css.

> App.css

Make a class in it named **distance**.

```
.distance{
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Then in your App.js import this css file as:

> import "./App.css"

And then use the **distance** class in your first image as follow:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={python} alt="python" height="50" className="distance" /> 
      <img src={java} alt="java" height="70" />
    </div>
  );
}
```